# Select all data from the first row i/e cell A5 to the last used colum and last used row for a border

Tags: excel, vba

VBA Code to select all data from the first row i/e cell A5, to the last used column and last used row for a border.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can google for that easily. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should find the last row of column A and then the last column of row 5. the below code select the range and apply `Outside Borders`.

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find the last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Find the last column of row 5
        LastColumn = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        With .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```